# How I can resolve `Font shape `xxx/it' undefined` warning for CJK in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, cjk

Below CJK-contains code compiles without errors however with warnings.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}

\setmainjfont[
    Path          = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont   = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
    BoldFont      = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc
]{HGS Mincho}

\setsansjfont[
    Path          = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont   = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGM.ttc,
    BoldFont      = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGE.ttc,
]{HGS Gothic}

\begin{document}    
    \section{フォント試験試験}  
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 主要フォント
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 漢あア
                \item \bfseries{漢あア}
            \end{itemize}
        \item ゴシックのフォント
            \begin{itemize}
                \item \sffamily{漢あア}
                \item \sffamily{\bfseries{漢あア}}
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The warning contents is:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JT3/mc/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `JT3/mc/m/n' instead on input line 3745.

*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
* 
* Font 'fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc' does not contain script 'CJK'.
```

I suppose, in `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'JT3/mc/m/it' undefined`, `JT3/mc/m/it` refers to italic shape. Normally CJK has not italic font style, so I don't care if I can not use it. However, I need this warning do not disturb me. Off course, muffle all warnings is not allowed approach.

`Font 'fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc' does not contain script 'CJK'.` is also requires an attention, however I cannot merge it in one question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the italic font and bold italic font to the same as the upright fonts. This will stop the warning.

```
\setmainjfont[
    Path           = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont    = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
    ItalicFont     = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
    BoldFont       = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc
    BoldItalicFont = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc
]{HGS Mincho}

\setsansjfont[
    Path           = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont    = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGM.ttc,
    ItalicFont     = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGM.ttc,
    BoldFont       = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGE.ttc,
    BoldItalicFont = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGE.ttc,
]{HGS Gothic}
```